# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Помогите найти ошибку, плиз.
Пытаюсь написать консольные крестики-нолики, однако один из циклов не думает заканчиваться, хотя вроде как все условия для этого выполнены. Сам цикл:

```
do {
    Scanner coord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(player1Name + ", введите номер ячейки по горизонтали (от 1 до 3):");
    x = coord.nextInt() - 1;
    System.out.println(player1Name + ", введите номер ячейки по вертикали (от 1 до 3):");
    y = coord.nextInt() - 1;

    if (field[x][y] == '_'){
        field[x][y] = 'X';
    } else {
        System.out.println("Это поле уже занято, попробуйте снова.");
    }
       for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                    System.out.print(field[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
} while (field[x][y] == 'X');
```

Проблема где-то здесь `while (field[x][y] == 'X');` насколько я понимаю, но в чем проблема, до меня не доходит.
Поле 3х3, если игрок введет координаты х = 1, у = 2,  то выведется поле вида

```
_ Х _
_ _ _
_ _ _
```

Т.е. как и должно, но проверку в конце цикла не проходит и опять начинает крутить сначала.

Ошибка полностью:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at Main.main(Main.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Проблема с бесконечным циклом ясна. Непонятно на каком шаге возникает `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: `at Main.main(Main.java:80)` т.е. как раз, где `while (field[x][y] == 'X');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу того почему цикл не заканчивается:

```
do {
    //...пропуск
    if (field[x][y] == '_'){
        field[x][y] = 'X'; //Здесь мы заполнили поле x,y
    } else {
        System.out.println("Это поле уже занято, попробуйте снова.");
    }
    //после этого field[x][y] обязательно Х
    //...пропуск
} while (field[x][y] == 'X'); //а здесь мы проверяем, что х,у заполнено: ответ всегда да
```

Т.е. проверка выбранного поля производится после его заполнения.

Выйти из цикла можно разными способами:

- сделать `break` из `if` при выборе пустого поля;
- создать переменную-флаг и отслеживать было ли выбрано пустое поле или нет;
- изменить структуру кода: в цикле только проверять возможность заполнения, а заполнять снаружи.

Почему возникает `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: переменные x и у используются повторно для распечатки массива, после выполнения циклов их значения меняются:

```
for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                System.out.print(field[x][y] + " ");
        }
        //здесь у = SIZE
        System.out.println();
}
//здесь x=SIZE
```

Исправить это можно если использовать для циклов локальные переменные

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
```

либо вообще отдельный метод для распечатки.

Comment: Спасибо, дошло наконец, почему цикл не заканчивался. Распечатка тут просто для проверки, что поле заполняется корректно.

Answer (score 4):

По окончании циклов:

```
for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                System.out.print(field[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

получится, что `x=y=SIZE;`

Далее вы пытаетесь извлечь `field[x][y]`, где `x, y` уже лежат за границами массива и естественно получаете в ответ грубость.

Пересмотрите логику.